# R return a data frame iterate through multidimensional dataframe using data entries as value to create new list entry.

Tags: r

I have a file path and a list of value in the form of

```
[path1, [value1,value2,value3,...]]
[path2, [valueA,valueB]]
```

I want to turn it into the form

```
path1, value1
path1, value2
path1, value3
.
.
.
path2, valueA
path2, valueB
.
.
.
```

I know I could do this with a foreach, but I am not sure how I would do this in base R.

I was close with

```
makeTuple<- function(path,value) 
{   
         result <- cbind(path,value)  
         return(result) 
} 
makeTupleList<- function(listFull) 
{   
         path <- listFull[1,1]   
         list <- listFull[1,2]   
         result <- lapply(list, makeTuple, path=path)   return(result) 
}
```

Test Values:

```
x <- list(c(1,2),c(3,4))
y <- cbind(c(5,6), x)
```

Results:

```
makeTupleList(y)
$x
     path value
[1,] 5    1    
[2,] 5    2
```

I am not sure how to get a data frame to go through each row.

In Haskell I would just do something like

```
tupleMake (x,list) =  [(x,y)| y <- list]
```

and then just path that over my list of tuples with the form 
(path, values)

Comment: so if you just `unlist` it and change the data type this is simply a matter of going from wide to long data (which there are way too many answers to on SO and Google already, so you can find good help by doing a search). The only complication is the varying width by row, but that's also well-covered ground. You can fill in the extra columns with NA's for the shorter rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood the problem correctly, this will work

```
result <- as.data.frame.matrix(cbind(rep(paths,sapply(values,length)),unlist(values)))
colnames(result) <- c("path","value")
```

**Data**

```
values <- list(c(1,2),c(3,4))
paths <- c(5,6)
```

Answer (score 0):

One option possibly worth trying, with `paths`, `values` from @user2100721:

```
do.call(rbind, Map(cbind, paths, values))
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    5    1
[2,]    5    2
[3,]    6    3
[4,]    6    4
```